# Joining of two queries and returning in list format

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I am developing a MVC application.

I am using the two queries to fetch the record, and I want to get the common records from these queries .

I want to return the data set in list

Like this

```
return Json(poList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

My two queries are..

```
 var poList = (from po in db.PurchaseOrders
                      where po.CompanyId == companyId && po.PartyId == partyId && (po.IsDeleted == false || po.IsDeleted == null)
                      select po into newPO
                      select new
                      {
                          Name = newPO.PONo,
                          Id = newPO.Id

                      }); 
                      //.ToList().OrderBy(e => e.Name);


      var poList2 = (db.Employees.Where(x => x.Id == EmpID)
          .SelectMany(x => x.Roles)
          .SelectMany(x => x.Employees)
          .Distinct()
          .SelectMany(x => x.PurchaseOrders)
          .Select(po => new { Name = po.PONo, Id = po.Id }));


        var finalPO = from PO in poList.ToList().Union(poList2).ToList() select PO);
```

Comment: Try:  var finalPO = from PO in poList.ToList().Union(poList2.ToList())

Comment: Read this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844660/differences-between-iqueryable-list-ienumerator/4844755 it should help you with your problem

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont not think you need the ToList() in the intermediate results, just use the union and do the ToList in the final result, like:

```
var finalPO = poList.Union(poList2).ToList()
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason you can't union them is that the two lists return different objects.

The first list returns an anonymous type with members `Name` and `Id`. If, instead, you just wanted to return the purchase orders in query one, then you could simply use the following:

```
var poList = (
    from po in db.PurchaseOrders
    where po.CompanyId == companyId && 
          po.PartyId == partyId && 
          (po.IsDeleted == false || po.IsDeleted == null)
     select po
);
```

You may need to append `.ToList()` to the query above in order to use the `Union(...)` method. Then, you should be able to union the two sequences together (assuming `poList2` is also a sequence of `db.PurhaseOrders` objects.

Conversely, instead of changing query for `poList` above, you could change the query behind `poList2` to the following to achieve the same effect, but different results:

```
var poList2 = (db.Employees.Where(x => x.Id == EmpID)
              .SelectMany(x => x.Roles)
              .SelectMany(x => x.Employees)
              .Distinct()
              .SelectMany(x => x.PurchaseOrders)
              .Select(po => new { Name = po.PONo, Id = po.Id }));
```

Personally, I think the first one is more clear (unless there are many fields on the PO object and you only need the two as shown).

**UPDATE:** I see the original post was edited so that both queries now return the same object (or shape of object). However, the poster is still trying to combine the results incorrectly. The poster is using yet another LINQ query in an attempt to use the `Union(...)` method. This is completely unnecessary. Might as well write out the code for him/her:

```
var finalPO = poList.Union(poList2).ToList(); // ToList() only necessary if you need a list back
```

That should do it.

Really, the two books I mentioned in my comments below will get you a long way in understanding .NET and LINQ: APress - Pro C# and the .NET Framework 4.0; O'Reilly - C# 5 in a Nutshell. There are also many books on LINQ alone--but without a solid grasp of .NET (and C#, F#, or VB), you can't hope to understand or use LINQ.

Comment: I suggest you read a good book on .NET and LINQ then. Try the Apress book Pro C# and the .NET Framework 4.0, or O'Reilly's C# in a Nutshell. What I've described above is basic knowledge you need to understand in order to effectively use LINQ.

Comment: Please check updated question...I understand about the difference what about the Join ? It showing error in last statement.

Comment: I don't see a `Join(...)` operator being used. If you mean the `Union` call, then see my answer above. You are trying to union together two sequences, but the sequences contain different objects. In your original queries, the first sequence returns a sequence of anonymous objects with shape `{Name, Id}`. The second sequence returns objects of type `db.PurchaseOrders`. You can't combine the two sequences--they are not the same type or shape.

Comment: ya , you are right but I am interested only in PoNo and ID. what changes I have to be done in 2nd query ?

Comment: Ok, use your first query as you have it in your OP. Then use the query shown in my answer for `poList2`. Then, both query sequences should have the same "shape" and so should be unionable.

Comment: it looks like both queries return the same anonymous type to me...Has the post been edited?

Answer (score 0):

First, create a ViewModel like this:

```
public class PurchaseOrderViewModel
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then, use it in your code like this:

```
var poList1 = (from po in db.PurchaseOrders
         where po.CompanyId == companyId && po.PartyId == partyId 
             && (po.IsDeleted == false || po.IsDeleted == null)
         select po into newPO
         select new PurchaseOrderViewModel
         {
             Name = newPO.PONo,
             Id = newPO.Id
         }).ToList(); 

var poList2 = (db.Employees.Where(x => x.Id == EmpID)
     .SelectMany(x => x.Roles)
     .SelectMany(x => x.Employees)
     .Distinct()
     .SelectMany(x => x.PurchaseOrders)
     .Select(po => new PurchaseOrderViewModel 
     { 
          Name = po.PONo, 
          Id = po.Id  
     })).ToList();

var finalList = poList1.Union(poList2);
```

Comment: where to write Viewmodel ? same class ?

Comment: No, a separate Class in your ViewModels folder. I'm assuming you want to pass the finalList to a View.