# Retrieving 10 records at a time only using LINQ

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I'm currently looking into server side paging and data calls for the kendoUI grid. I can get the grid to perform the server side transaction but I have notices that even if a select all or select the top 10 the reads to the SQL database are the same.

When returning all the records - it gets a sql profiler read of 104
When returning only 10 records - it gets a sql profiler read of 104, as well

Function used to return the data

```
public List<Employee> GetEmployees(int take, int skip)

{

return GetRepo<Employee>().All(null).where(p => p.IsDeleted == false).OrderBy(p => p.EmployeeNumber).Skip(10).Take(10).ToList();

}
```

When the LINQ performs the 10 record call, I have used the built in .Skip() and .Take() functions. This method require an .OrderBy() function to work, and I have order by the Id column on the table.

When you use the .Skip() and .Take() functions, it wraps a top 10 on the outside of the same query used to call all the records at once. Please see the sql extract taken from sql profiler,

```
SELECT TOP (10) *
FROM ( SELECT *, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Project1].[EmployeeNumber] ASC) AS [row_number]
FROM ( SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id]
AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[FirstName]
AS [FirstName], 
[Extent1].[LastName]
AS [LastName], 
[Extent2].[EmployeeNumber]
AS [EmployeeNumber], 
[Extent2].[WeeklyHours]
AS [WeeklyHours], 
'0X0X'  AS [C1]

FROM [dbo].[Person]
AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN  [dbo].[Employee] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[Id]
WHERE 0 = [Extent2].[IsDeleted]
)  AS [Project1]
)  AS [Project1]
WHERE [Project1].[row_number] > 0
ORDER BY [Project1].[EmployeeNumber] ASC
```

The project is a asp.net MVC project and using framework 4.5.

Is there a way to return the 10 records back without having to scan through the whole table? As the employee and person table will grow to be more than 1 million active records at any time.

If this is in the wrong category, my apologies for that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using List, try to use IQueryable or IEnumerable. Below is an example:

```
public IQueryable<Employee> GetEmployees(int take, int skip)
{
   return GetRepo<Employee>().All(null).where(p => p.IsDeleted == false).OrderBy(p => p.EmployeeNumber).Skip(10).Take(10);
}
```

Note:

> **IQueryable** is intended to allow a query provider (for example, an ORM like LINQ to SQL or the Entity Framework) to use the
>   expressions contained in a query to translate the request into another
>   format. In other words, LINQ-to-SQL looks at the properties on the
>   entities that you're using along with the comparisons you're making
>   and actually creates a SQL statement to express (hopefully) an
>   equivalent request.
>
> **IEnumerable** is more generic than IQueryable (though all instances of IQueryable implement IEnumerable) and only defines
>   a sequence. However, there are extension methods available within the
>   Enumerable class that define some query-type operators on that
>   interface and use ordinary code to evaluate these conditions.
>
> **List** is just an output format, and while it implements IEnumerable, is not directly related to querying.

For more details, take a look at below link:

[Differences between IQueryable, List, IEnumerator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844660/differences-between-iqueryable-list-ienumerator)

**Update**

If you have a filter defined in the IRepository interface class like below

```
IQueryable<T> Filter(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter);
```

You can change the GetEmployees method like below:

```
public IQueryable<Employee> GetEmployees(int take, int skip)
{
   return GetRepo<Employee>().Filter(p => p.IsDeleted == false).OrderBy(p => p.EmployeeNumber).Skip(10).Take(10);
}
```

The reason is to make the query deferred.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, @Lin. I have tried both IQueryable and IEnumerable but the SQL produced still scans the whole table and the takes what is needs. Even when creating a sql script in sql server management studio and using the 'rank() over(Order by)' function, the number of reads are the same.

Comment: hi @pchannon, what is the return type of GetRepo<Employee>().All(), if it's List<T>, you need to change it to IQqueryable.

Comment: The return type of GetRepo<Employee>() is IRepository. Please a little code snippet below `public static IRepository<T> GetRepo<T>() where T : class
        {
            var factory = new PayrollRepositories<T>();
            return factory.GetRepository();
        }`

Comment: I guess you should check the "All" method definition in the IRepository. It should look like "IQueryable<T> All()". also I'm sure why you're returning static IRepository<T>.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance @Lin. I found a way to lower the reads on the database by using the original statement by adding **.AsQueryable** to the call. Eg `return GetRepo<Employee>().All(null).AsQueryable().where(p => p.IsDeleted == false).OrderBy(p => p.EmployeeNumber).Skip(10).Take(10).ToList();`. This has brought the reads down from 104 to 6. This will save the database load in the future.

Comment: did the SQL sent to DB as viewed in SQL profiler actually change?