# Linq Sum() precision

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, nhibernate, floating-point-precision

In my project I have been using `Linq's Sum()` a lot. It's powered by NHibernate on MySQL. In my `Session Factory` I have explicitly asked NHibernate to deal with exactly 8 decimal places when it comes to `decimals`:

```
public class DecimalsConvention : IPropertyConvention
{
    public void Apply(IPropertyInstance instance)
    {
        if (instance.Type.GetUnderlyingSystemType() == typeof(decimal))
        {
            instance.Scale(8);
            instance.Precision(20);
        }
    }
}
```

However, I found out that `.Sum()` rounds up the numbers in 5 decimal places:

`var opasSum = opasForThisIp.Sum(x => x.Amount);  // Amount is a decimal`

In the above statement `opaSum` equals to **2.46914** while it should be **2.46913578** (calculated directly on MySQL). `opasForThisIp` is of type `IQueryable<OutgoingPaymentAssembly>`.

I need all the Linq calculations to handle 8 decimal places when it comes to `decimals`.

Any ideas of how to fix this?

**Edit 1**: I have found `var opasSum = Enumerable.Sum(opasForThisIp, opa => opa.Amount);` to produce the correct result, however the question remains, why `.Sum()` rounds up the result and how can we fix it?

**Edit 2**: The produced SQL seems to be problematic:

```
select cast(sum(outgoingpa0_.Amount) as DECIMAL(19,5)) as col_0_0_ 
from `OutgoingPaymentAssembly` outgoingpa0_ 
where outgoingpa0_.IncomingPayment_id=?p0 
and (outgoingpa0_.OutgoingPaymentTransaction_id is not null);
?p0 = 24 [Type: UInt64 (0)]
```

**Edit 3**: `var opasSum = opasForThisIp.ToList().Sum(x => x.Amount);` also produces the correct result.

**Edit 4**: Converting the `IQueryable<OutgoingPaymentAssembly>` to an `IList<OutgoingPaymentAssembly>` made the original query: `var opasSum = opasForThisIp.Sum(x => x.Amount);` to work.

Comment: When running `var opasSum = opasForThisIp.Sum(x => x.Amount);`, have you checked the generated SQL statement?

Comment: @DominicKexel great remark, there is a problem in the SQL statement indeed, see my edit.

Comment: I don't get this. The `.Sum()` is really `Enumerable.Sum()`'s extension method, why does it produce different SQL statement?

Comment: What type is opasForThisIp?

Comment: @dotsamuelswan it's an `IQueryable<OutgoingPaymentAssembly>` collection.

Comment: I'd be curious to see what happens to the generated SQL if you force the IQueryable to a list.  var opasSum = opasForThisIp.ToList().Sum(x => x.Amount);  It seems like it should have the same effect as calling Enumerable.Sum(), but I can't say for sure.

Comment: @dotsamuelswan you are right, `opasForThisIp.ToList().Sum(x => x.Amount);` produces the correct result indeed. Why do you think this happens?

Comment: It seems somewhat likely that IQueryable<T> might treat the statements as linq to SQL, which might explain why you'd be getting the precision problem outlined from MSDN in my answer below.

Comment: @dotsamuelswan converting the `IQueryable<OutgoingPaymentAssembly>` to an `IList<OutgoingPaymentAssembly>` made the original query `var opasSum = opasForThisIp.Sum(x => x.Amount);` to work. I still don't get it, though.

Comment: I'll update my answer to reflect my findings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

x.Amount is being converted to a low precision minimum type from "LINQ-to-SQL" conversion, because your collection is IQueryable.

There are several workarounds, the easiest of which is to change the type of your collection to IList, or call ToList() on your collection, forcing the linq query to run as LINQ-to-Objects.

```
var opasSum = opasForThisIp.ToList().Sum(x => x.Amount);
```

*Note:*
*If you don't want to lose deferred execution by moving away from the IQueryable, you could try casting the Amount to a decimal inside of the linq query.*

From [MSDN decimal and numeric (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx):

> In Transact-SQL statements, a constant with a decimal point is
>   automatically converted into a numeric data value, using the minimum
>   precision and scale necessary. For example, the constant 12.345 is
>   converted into a numeric value with a precision of 5 and a scale of 3.

**Edit** (to include great explanation of different .NET collection types:

Taken from the answer to [this SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844660/differences-between-iqueryable-list-ienumerator)

> IQueryable is intended to allow a query provider (for example, an
>   ORM like LINQ to SQL or the Entity Framework) to use the expressions
>   contained in a query to translate the request into another format. In
>   other words, LINQ-to-SQL looks at the properties on the entities that
>   you're using along with the comparisons you're making and actually
>   creates a SQL statement to express (hopefully) an equivalent request.
>
> IEnumerable is more generic than IQueryable (though all
>   instances of IQueryable implement IEnumerable) and only defines
>   a sequence. However, there are extension methods available within the
>   Enumerable class that define some query-type operators on that
>   interface and use ordinary code to evaluate these conditions.
>
> List is just an output format, and while it implements
>   IEnumerable, is not directly related to querying.
>
> In other words, when you're using IQueryable, you're defining and
>   expression that gets translated into something else. Even though
>   you're writing code, that code never gets executed, it only gets
>   inspected and turned into something else, like an actual SQL query.
>   Because of this, only certain things are valid within these
>   expressions. For instance, you cannot call an ordinary function that
>   you define from within these expressions, since LINQ-to-SQL doesn't
>   know how to turn your call into a SQL statement. Most of these
>   restrictions are only evaluated at runtime, unfortunately.
>
> When you use IEnumerable for querying, you're using
>   LINQ-to-Objects, which means you are writing the actual code that is
>   used for evaluating your query or transforming the results, so there
>   are, in general, no restrictions on what you can do. You can call
>   other functions from within these expressions freely.

Comment: Additionally, you may have some luck checking out SqlFunctions methods.  I don't know much about them myself.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions(v=vs.110).aspx