# Entity Framework & MemoryCache

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, caching

I have an n-tier application ASP.NET MVC. I use entity framework in DAL.
So i decided to use cache layer in dal for up app's performance. I've implement it but there is a problem. I put entity to memory cache first request after that when second request i try to get entity from cache it's throw object disposed error. I know this error normal because i can't it from cache. But i couldn't think it.
What can i do? Should i use business object in dal or?

"The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection"

```
    public IQueryable<Category> GetAll()
    {
        var cacheKey = string.Format("{0}_{1}", "CategoryRepository", "GetAll");

        var isExists = _cache.Contains(cacheKey) && Const.CacheIsActive;
        if (isExists)
        {
               //At here error: "The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and 
               //can no longer be used for operations that require a connection"
            return _cache.Get<IQueryable<Category>>(cacheKey);
        }
        else
        {
            var obj = _db.Categories;
            _cache.Add(cacheKey, obj);

            return obj;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `_db.Categories` is an `IQueryable`, and only contains instructions on how to get data (not store it).  Try saving `_db.Categories.ToList()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Differences between IQueryable, List, IEnumerator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844660/differences-between-iqueryable-list-ienumerator)

Comment: You are right. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

in context write

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
        {
            if (options != null)
            {
                options.UseMemoryCache(_cache);
            }
        }
```