# Filtering by two different fields based on a list

Tags: asp.net-core, filter

The end goal is to have an infinite scroll only showing items that fall into the user preferences. Currently, the infinite part hasn’t been set up yet, but as you look through this please keep the future goal in mind in case that would impact the “best” way to accomplish this. This project is ASP.NET Core.

Each item has location and category indicators, and while I’d like to go two-deep for now I’m just doing one level in. So instead of doing country and state, I’m just doing country. To achieve this I need a way for the user to 1) indicate what their preferences are, 2) mark the items with those stats, and 3) filter out the items that don’t match both location and category.

1) To mark preferences, we’re using bool on the user model:

```
public bool Country1 { get; set; }
public bool Country2 { get; set; }
…
public bool Cat1_1 { get; set; }
public bool Cat1_2 { get; set; }
…
```

2) To mark the items with those stats on the forum model:

```
public int ForumCat1 { get; set; }
public int? ForumCat2 { get; set; }
…
public int? ForumCountry { get; set; }
public int? ForumState { get; set; }
…
```

3) To filter out the items that don’t match both in the code behind we’re using this:

```
public IList<Forum> ForumPosts { get; set; }

public async Task OnGetAsync()
  {
    var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);

    var countryFilters = new List<int>();
    var cat1Filters = new List<int>();

    if (user.Country1) { countryFilters.Add(1); }
    if (user.Country2) { countryFilters.Add(2); }
    ….
    if (user.Cat1_1) { cat1Filters.Add(1); }
    if (user.Cat1_2) { cat1Filters.Add(2); }
    …
    var countryList = _appDbContext.Country.ToList();
    var cat1List = _appDbContext.Cat1.ToList();

    var forumPosts =  _appDbContext.Forum.ToList();
    ForumPosts = new List<Forum>();

    foreach (var countryId in countryFilters)
       {                
          foreach (var cat1Id in cat1Filters)
            {
              var forums = _appDbContext.Forum.Where(c => c.ForumCat1 == cat1Id && c.ForumCountry==countryId).ToList();
              foreach (var post in forums)
                {
                            ForumPosts.Add(post);       
                 }
              }
        }
  }
```

While this works, it seems inefficient to me. It seems to me that I should be able to do something like:

```
For each (var post in forumPosts)
  {
    If countryFilter.contains(forumcountry) && cat1Filter.contains(forumCat1)
       {
        ForumPosts.Add(post)
       }
  }
```

That doesn’t work, or at least I can’t get it to work. There is also the problem of saving the list/collection in the database and having to create it on the fly for each query, but I don’t see that as having as much overhead as cycling through the database 8 times to apply the filtering so I’m more interested if anyone knows a more efficient way to achieve this?

From Lukáš suggestion this works and is much cleaner/more efficient. Thanks!

```
    var forumMatches = _appDbContext.Forum.Where(c => countryFilters.Contains(c.ForumCountry) && cat1Filters.Contains(c.ForumCat1)).AsEnumerable();
    ForumPosts = new List<Forum>();
    ForumPosts.AddRange(forumMatches);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is what you want :)

```
_appDbContext.Forum.Where(c => countryFilters.Contains(c.ForumCat1) && cat1Filters.Contains(c.ForumCountry))
```

Answer (score 0):

@Coveny You would probably want to call `.AsQueryable()` rather than `.ToList()` on your `countryFilters` & `cat1Filters` You might ran into performance impact if your collections are too big to iterate in memory.

Take a look at this
[Differences between IQueryable, List, IEnumerator?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4844755/4444844)